# Test decorators with arguments are always executed

Tags: python, decorator, pytest, python-unittest, python-decorators

What I'm trying to achieve is to put setup code needed by certain tests inside a decorator function. I *deliberately avoided* `setUp` and `tearDown` methods because they are shared by all the tests inside the test case and that is not what I'm looking for. It's more a matter of personal preferences and interest in learning rather than go for the straight forward solution.

Simplified version of the code:

```
# some import lines
from some.package import interceptor

class TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple_thing(self):
        # simple stuff

    def test_another_simple_thing(self):
        # more simple stuff

    @interceptor(arg1, arg2)
    def test_with_some_preparation_needed(self):
        # hey! Really cool stuff in here

    print('This will be executed with every test')

    @interceptor(arg1, arg2, namedarg1='foo', namedarg2='bar')
    def test_with_preparation_also(self):
        # the first decorator is executed
        # sure I'm not following Python's Zen
```

The decorator function:

```
from wsgi_intercept import requests_intercept
from wsgi_intercept import add_wsgi_intercept


def interceptor(cityname, response, host='localhost', port=8000):
    requests_intercept.install()
    add_wsgi_intercept(host, port,
                       lambda: create_webservice(cityname, response))

    def decorator(test):

        def runtest(self):
            test(self)
            requests_intercept.uninstall()

        return runtest

    return decorator


def create_webservice(cityname, response):

    def app(environ, start_response):
        # a simple WSGI app

    return app
```

Each decorator is a function call with arguments because I need to parameterize the setup. The invocation returns the real decorator for the test. The problem is that they are like any other statement placed in between function definitions and so they get executed.

Is viable this idea of test decorators with arguments the way I'm doing it? Maybe with data providers it will possible.

Comment: Functions are decorated *when module loads*. So, yes, the `mydecorator(arg1, arg2)` and `mydecorator(arg1, arg2, namedarg1='foo', namedarg2='bar')` expressions are *always* executed. Show us your actual decorators for us to be able to help you sort out where to put code only executed when the `test_with_some_preparation_needed` and `test_with_preparation_also` methods are executed.

Comment: The `print()` call is part of the class body, so yes, that'll get executed as well. I'm actually not sure what your question is here; the `print()` function has nothing to do with the decorators here.

Comment: The `print()` line is just an example of what I mean when I say 'like any other statement placed in between function definitions and so they get executed'.

Comment: I tried to put the decorator function inside the test class, outside it and in an imported module and the result was the same. I know I can solve this simply by calling some utility functions at the beginning and end of the tests when needed, but the decorator approach seems more clean to me.

Comment: I strongly suggest ditching unittest and using py.test instead, since it has [fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html). If you ping me when this is reopened, I could expand this into an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe I've clarified a little bit the question. Could you reopen it?

Comment: @o11c I'm gradually switching to pytest and is being easy so far. However, AFAIK all fixture examples involve passing data to the tests and not the other way around. Ideally I would like that my test could pass variables to the fixture through its own parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move everything that you want executed *per test* into the `runtest` wrapper. Both the `interceptor()` decorator factory and the `decorator` itself are executed *when the `TestWhatever` class object is created*:

```
def interceptor(cityname, response, host='localhost', port=8000):    
    def decorator(test):
        def runtest(self):
            requests_intercept.install()
            add_wsgi_intercept(
                host, port,
                lambda: create_webservice(cityname, response))
            test(self)
            requests_intercept.uninstall()
        return runtest    
    return decorator
```

Note that the *normal* pattern is to still use `setUp` and `tearDown`, and to put *only* those tests that need that specific setup in that class. You can always add more `TestCase` classes without that setup for the other tests:

```
class TestWhateverWithSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        requests_intercept.install()
        add_wsgi_intercept(
            host, port,
            lambda: create_webservice(cityname, response))

    def tearDown(self):
        requests_intercept.uninstall()

    def test_with_some_preparation_needed(self):
        # hey! Really cool stuff in here

    def test_with_preparation_also(self):
        # the first decorator is executed
        # sure I'm not following Python's Zen


class TestWhateverWithoutSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_thing(self):
        # simple stuff

    def test_another_simple_thing(self):
        # more simple stuff
```

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. Neat. I will do what you suggest. Anyway, it was interesting to know about `py.test` and I will further explore another options.